# How to select by condition on JSON column in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter, conditional-statements

How to write query for selecting data by where condition on column having JSON array?
i.e.
Suppose I have added user_name, user_role in ci_sessions. and user_data is JSON array.

```
SELECT *
FROM `ci_sessions` where user_data[user_role]='admin';
                 *********************/\***************
```

This where condition is needs to be designed. I require data with having user_role "admin".

Update: To check user_role "admin" is main objective of where condition.

Is there any way to add where condition as `user_data[user_role]` or `user_data->user_role`?

**Update:** This is possible in PostgresSQL DB.

Comment: This is a terrible design. If you need to query for a user_role field, it should be its own column.

Comment: I know it's terrible design. But the professionals on Stack Overflow are very intelligent. Is it never possible with query? Or by writing subquery? Anything?

Comment: So isn't possible at all to check this condition by sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was keep on waiting for this type of query but I failed to do so. That's why I had made combination of sql and php.

1. I have got results from all ci_sessions table.
2. Then I checked in result by decoding field of JSON arraY. aND it's working fine.

> ```
> SELECT * FROM `ci_sessions`;
> ```

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
            $user_data=$row->user_data;
            foreach (unserialize($user_data) as $k => $v) {
                $final[] = array('key' => $k, 'value' => $v);
                if($k=='user_role' && $v='admin') {
//make array of admin information required to show
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what you're doing there, but you just call `$this->session->userdata('user_role')` and CI's automatically chooses how to retrieve that value. If you set (and I think you did) to use a database, the query will be performed automatically.

I don't understand how you actually saved your session variable, if you json_encoded() by yourself or you are referring to the encoding performed by CI.

In the latter, you just:

```
if($this->session->userdata('user_role') == 'admin')
{
 // do stuff
}
```

Otherwise, `$role = json_decode($this->session->userdata('user_role'));` and the examine the array but I can't help you much here since you didn't provide clear information

Comment: By this: $this->session->userdata('user_role') == 'admin', I will get only user is admin or not. I want to display users who are 'admin' and those are logged in now. Can I get those by query?

Comment: Is it never possible with query? Or by writing subquery? Anything?